# Disable Unnecessary escape character: \+

Tags: regex, validation, next.js, eslint, phone-number

I have this regex of mine that will validate phone number (i.e. +1 (417) 230-0718). Using this regex `/^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/im`, I've encountered and error while running my test cases in next about Unnecessary escape character: +. How to disable this eslint-error in order for me to proceed with my test case and use the regex.

Appreciate for any help!

Comment: Well, remove the redundant escape character (you don’t need to escape most special characters inside `[…]`, and the rest of your regex already doesn’t do this — e.g. you write `[(]` instead of `[\(]`).

Comment: so I should use this regex /^[+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/im;
right?

Comment: Konrad Rudolph, thanks. It work correctly without any warning.
I'm really thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example phone number does not match your original regex and that contains multiple unnecessary escapes.

To answer your initial question first: in a `[]` part, you don't need to escape characters - the only character with a special meaning is the `^`, and that also only has a special meaning as the first character inside `[]` so you can put it further back. Also you don't need `[]` for only one character - then the escaped version is better.

Next to your regex not matching your example phone number:
You are missing the international prefix after the + sign in the beginning.

I would rewrite your regex to the following:

```
/^(?:\+\d{1,3}[-\s.]?)?\(?[0-9]{3}\)?[-\s.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/m
```

You don't need the *i* flag as there are no upper/lower case digits.

This updated regex allows for an optional 1 to 3 digit international prefix, but that has to be preceded with a `+`

Comment: "the only character with a special meaning is the `^`" This is incorrect. There's `-` (when between two characters), and `]` and also backslash itself.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct way for this issue.

```
/^[+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s.]?[0-9]{4,6}$/im
```